# Why is HasCollidables mixin not being recognized in FlameGame?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flame

In my programm the HasCollidables Mixin is not beeing recognized. When I hover over "HasCollidables" it says "Classes can only mix in mixins and classes. (dartmixin_of_non_class)". I have the up to date Flutter Version (3.3.10) my Flame Version is 1.5.0.

```
import 'package:flame/geometry.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/components.dart';

void main() {
  var game = MyGame();
  runApp(
    GameWidget(
      game: game,
    ),
  );
}

class MyGame extends FlameGame with HasCollidables {
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    print('loading assets');
  }
```

Is something wrong with the code? I saw the exact code running on other machines.

I tried out adding and removing imports to fix the problem and also to update flutter and flame to the newest version, but that didn't help so far.

Comment: Comments are not for answers. Comments are for soliciting clarifications and improvements to the question. That is what I came here to do, and that is what I did.

Comment: Read the documentation and check updated syntax for Collidbles: https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.0.0/collision_detection.html

Comment: @Prashant If I understood it correctly my code looks exactly like in [link](https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.0.0/collision_detection.html#hascollidables). I can't find the mistake

Comment: Link posted by @Prshant is outdated. Here is the link to latest Flame docs on collision detection https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.5.0/flame/collision_detection.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HasCollidables` is deprecated now. You probably want to use `HasCollisionDetection` mixin. Read the docs here: https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.5.0/flame/collision_detection.html